# Different outcome for buffer operation when run in Jupyter NB versus CLI

Tags: buffer, geopandas

I have a Jupyter notebook which takes coordinates as inputs with a radius in meters to buffer the coordinate and create a polygon. There are cases where I have null coordinates and radii. In Jupyter I get `None` as a result (this suits me fine), however when I run the same code in a generic python script in the Linux subsystem in windows I get the following error:
`No Shapely geometry can be created from null value`.

The framework versions etc all match. Is there anyway I can ignore these errors and fill the geometry with `None` or an empty geometry as it currently does in the Jupyter notebook?

The following snippet is what I am using to perform the operation:

```py
# create point as geometry from given coordiantes

data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data.serving_longitude, data.serving_latitude)) 

# set then change CRS to a meters based EPSG system

data = data.set_crs('EPSG:4326').to_crs('EPSG:3857')

# buffer the coordinates by the radii/serving_dist to create a polygon - its this point where it keeps failing when run in the CLI

data['geometry'] = data.buffer(data.serving_dist) 

# cast crs back to normal lat lon

data = data.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
```

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: oh, ok thanks. I didnt realise! I'm self taught/learning for work, so some oversights like this are a nuisance! What projections would you recommend for distance based analysis?